# "Expression is not assignable" -- Problem assigning float as sum of two other floats in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, ios, floating-point, variable-assignment, cgrect

In a piano app, I'm assigning the coordinates of the black keys.
Here is the line of code causing the error.

'blackKey' and 'whiteKey' are both customViews

```
blackKey.center.x = (whiteKey.frame.origin.x + whiteKey.frame.size.width);
```

Comment: Note that `whiteKey.frame.origin.x + whiteKey.frame.size.width` is the same as `CGRectGetMaxX(whiteKey.frame)`.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The other answers don't exactly explain what's going on here, so this is the basic problem:

When you write `blackKey.center.x`, the `blackKey.center` and `center.x` both look like struct member accesses, but they're actually completely different things. `blackKey.center` is a property access, which desugars to something like `[blackKey center]`, which in turn desugars to something like `objc_msgSend(blackKey, @selector(center))`. You can't modify the return value of a function, like `objc_msgSend(blackKey, @selector(center)).x = 2` — it just isn't meaningful, because the return value isn't *stored* anywhere meaningful.

So if you want to modify the struct, you have to store the return value of the property in a variable, modify the variable, and then set the property to the new value.

Comment: We can set `anObject.anNonStructProperty.anProperty = someValue` right? How do you say that we can not modify the return value of a function. Can you please explain?

Comment: @EmptyStack: When you write `anObject.someProperty = something`, that is not equivalent to `[anObject someProperty] = something` — instead, it's equivalent to `[anObject setSomeProperty:something]`. You're sending a message to the object to call a setter method. You aren't assigning to the method's return value. The appearance of an assignment is just syntactic sugar, just like the appearance of a member access is syntactic sugar for a getter method.

Comment: I still don't get it clearly. Even in your answer, `blackKey.center` internally calls `objc_msgSend(blackKey, @selector(setCenter:))` and not `objc_msgSend(blackKey, @selector(center))` right?

Comment: @Adithya: No. If you think `blackKey.center` calls `setCenter:`, then what do you imagine the argument is? `[blackKey setCenter: ?????]`. It's just `[blackKey center]`.

Answer (score 19):

You can not directly change the `x` value of a `CGPoint`(or any value of a struct) like that, if it is an property of an object. Do something like the following.

```
CGPoint _center = blackKey.center;
_center.x =  (whiteKey.frame.origin.x + whiteKey.frame.size.width);
blackKey.center = _center;
```

Answer (score 10):

```
blackKey.center = CGPointMake ( whiteKey.frame.origin.x + whiteKey.frame.size.width, blackKey.center.y);
```

One way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative using macros:

```
#define CGPOINT_SETX(point, x_value) { \
    CGPoint tempPoint = point;         \
    tempPoint.x = (x_value);           \
    point = tempPoint;                 \
}

#define CGPOINT_SETY(point, y_value) { \
    CGPoint tempPoint = point;         \
    tempPoint.y = (y_value);           \
    point = tempPoint;                 \
}

CGPOINT_SETX(blackKey.center, whiteKey.frame.origin.x + whiteKey.frame.size.width);
```

or slightly simpler:

```
CGPOINT_SETX(blackKey.center, CGRectGetMaxX(whiteKey.frame));
```

Comment: Do you really need the `do ... while(0)`? Isn't the block scope `{ ... }`  enough to declare the temp variables (without potentially name-colliding with something just outside), and have the statements within executed exactly once?

Comment: @NicolasMiari I've been using `do ... while(0)` for such a long time that I didn't realize that `{...}` blocks work just fine. Thanks. Simplifying.

Comment: The reasoning for the `do ... while(0)` is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros For my case it isn't necessary, but there are cases where it is.

Answer (score 0):

As its meanings, you can't assign value to expression. For instance, a + b = c it is forbidden.