# expression isn't not assign,mapkit

Tags: objective-c, ios6, mapkit, mkcoordinateregion

Iam trying to display a map kit and I am doing the following :
MapViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
@interface SiteViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (assign, nonatomic)       MKCoordinateRegion  region;
@property (strong, nonatomic)       IBOutlet MKMapView  *googleMap;

@end
```

MapViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Set propertiesfor the mapView
    self.region.center.latitude         =   43.62862 ; // expression is not assigned
    self.region.center.longitude        =   -79.331245;// expression is not assigned
    self.region.span.longitudeDelta     =   0.01f;     // expression is not assigned
    self.region.span.longitudeDelta     =   0.01f;     // expression is not assigned
    [self.googleMap setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [self.googleMap setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [self.googleMap setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.googleMap setRegion:self.region animated:YES];


    MKPointAnnotation *pin = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    pin.coordinate  = region.center;
    [self.googleMap addAnnotation:pin];
}
```

I am getting

> expression is not assigned

I dont get it. Can somebody get explain and get me out of this trouble.

Comment: I think you'll find this similar question helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074405/expression-is-not-assignable-problem-assigning-float-as-sum-of-two-other-fl

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the mapview region via the region property or the method `- (void)setRegion:(MKCoordinateRegion)region animated:(BOOL)animated;`.

Try this:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(43.62862, -79.331245);

[self.mapView setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01f, 0.01f))];
```