# How to fetch and store value as coordinate from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, apple-maps

I am assigning value of latitude and longitude from one viewcontroller which are declared in another viewcontroller.
 but I am getting an error expression is not assignable

Here is my code:

```
mapVC.coordinate.latitude=[[tempArray objectAtIndex:9] doubleValue];
```

and here is my response:

```
 (
    17,
    TGB,
    Ahmedabad,
    "SG Highway",
    Dover,
    Georgia,
    388306,
    12345,
    "www.tgb.com",
    "37.23909",//latitude
    "-122.34567",//longitude
    "Dec 6, 2013 5:11:15 PM"
)
```

Comment: what is the type of latitude and coordinate?

Comment: CLLocationCoordinate2D

Comment: The answer to this question may be the answer to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074405/expression-is-not-assignable-problem-assigning-float-as-sum-of-two-other-fl

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the definition of your cell object and its properties.

You also need to describe your object graph. I gather it's an array that contains a dictionary, and that the key "latitude" in that inner dictionary contains an NSNumber or a string?

At a guess, your cell object's c1 property is of type CLLocationCoordinate2D.

When you have a property that's a struct, you can't change one part of the struct.
Another issue: If your cell's c1 property is a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, that's a scalar type. Your object structure (array that contains a dictionary?) can't directly contain a scalar value. It would have to be an NSNumber or (as the other poster suggested) an NSString)

You would have to rewrite it like this:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = cell.c1;
coordinate.latitude = [[[tempArray objectAtIndex:9] objectForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
cell.c1 = coordinate;
```