# Set iAd Frame Origin in code

Tags: ios, frame, iad

I have an iAd which I want to be able to change the placement on the y axis in code.
The ad is called on and spawned by this code:

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [UIWebView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I tried to change the position of the ad by doing something like this:

```
banner.frame.origin.y += 100;
```

or

```
banner.frame.origin.y = 100;
```

But I'm always left with the error:
Expression is not assignable

Comment: origin and size are readonly, you should use setFrame directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly assign frame position directly on an UIView. You have to:

```
CGRect frame = banner.frame;
frame.origin.y += 100; //Or whatever change you want to perform.
banner.frame = frame;
```

If you feel curious about why this happens, check out this answer here at stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7074522/1152596