# setup AFNetworking 3.x singleton Request and Response serialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, afnetworking

Hi i'm using AFNetworking 3.x. I have built a singleton for network api

```
+ (ApiClient *)sharedInstance {
    static ApiClient *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:SINGPOST_BASE_URL] sessionConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];

    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    if ((self = [super initWithBaseURL:url])) {
        AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
        [serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    }

    return self;
}
```

i want to setup the Request and Response Serialisation when using the singleton. How can we do that

I write these code keep getting error. any help is much appreciate. Thanks

```
[[[ApiClient sharedInstance]requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer] requestWithMethod:POST_METHOD URLString:urlString parameters:xml error:nil]];
```

my response serialization

```
ApiClient sharedInstance].responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [[ApiClient sharedInstance].responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
```

[image]

Comment: hi updated question with the error. what is proper way to setup request and response serialization?

Comment: Hi ApiClient already inherit from AFHTTPSessionManager

Comment: Have a look at this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074405/expression-is-not-assignable-problem-assigning-float-as-sum-of-two-other-fl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change your call `[AFHTTPRequestSerializer requestWithMethod..]` to

```
[[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:POST_METHOD URLString:urlString parameters:xml error:nil];
```

`AFHTTPRequestSerializer` don't have a class method `requestWithMethod` it need the first create a instance and after call `requestWithMethod`

Your code will look like:

```
[[ApiClient sharedInstance] requestSerializer] = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:POST_METHOD URLString:urlString parameters:xml error:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But does it apply to the singleton ApiClient?

Comment: thanks so i'll change the request serialization to [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:POST_METHOD URLString:urlString parameters:xml error:nil]?;. how about the response serialization is this correct?

Comment: No you just need `[[ApiClient sharedInstance].responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];`

Comment: thanks, can we include these 2 in the initiation of singleton also because have arround 50 similar one everytime need these 2 setup

Comment: Yes you can if you have for all response `acceptableContentTypes ` text/html and all of your requests have a POST_METHOD type

Comment: it will under method + (ApiClient *)sharedInstance { or - (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    if ((self = [super initWithBaseURL:url])) {
        AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
        [serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    }

    return self;
}?